# D3js force directed graph linkStrength blocked to 0

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm encountering some problem with d3js and the force directed layout:

Links are weak like if linkStrength() were set to 0. But changing it doesn't change anything.

When i drag a node, the others doesn't move...

**EDIT :**

**I've found that by changing data to classic integer-indexed array, everything is ok!**
I don't know why key-value arrays or object doesn't work ...

Here is my code:

```
tick =  ->
    link
    .attr "x1", (d) ->
        nodes[d.source].x
    .attr "y1", (d) ->
        nodes[d.source].y
    .attr "x2", (d) ->
        nodes[d.target].x
    .attr "y2", (d) ->
        nodes[d.target].y

circles
    .attr "cx", (d) ->
        d.x
    .attr "cy", (d) ->
        d.y


nodes_values = d3.values nodes

force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes nodes_values
    .links links
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .on 'tick', tick
    .start()

link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data links
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr "marker-end", "url(#arrow)"




groups = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data nodes_values
    .enter()
    .append 'g'


circles = groups
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr "r", (d)-> 
        if d.weigth
            return d.weigth * 5
        else 
            return 5
    .style "fill", (d) -> color d.group
    .call(force.drag)
```

And data looks like:

Links:

```
"[
 {
  "source": "xxxx.xxxx@xxxxx.xx",
  "target": "NIWT",
 },
 {
  "source": "yyyyy.yyyyy@yyyyyy.yyy",
  "target": "NIUT",
 }
]"
```

Nodes:

```
 {
        "xxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx" : {
            "name":"xxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx",
            "group":"Operateurs",
            "weight":0,
            "x":386.20246469091313,
            "y":282.4477932203487,
            "px":386.337157279126,
            "py":282.4570376593727,
        },
        "yyyyy.yyyyy@yyyyy.yyyy": {
            "name":"yyyyy.yyyyy@yyyyy.yyyy",
            "group":"Operateurs",
            "weight":0,
            "x":853.3548980089732,
            "y":395.80903774295444,
            "px":853.2517240837253,
            "py":395.7616750529105
        }
    }
```

Did you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the links array that you pass to the force layout.

**The source and target values of your links need to be pointers to the actual node data objects**, not just string ids.  That way, when the d3 force layout scans through the array of links, it can access the data objects and adjust the x and y values according to the link strength.

To fix, you need to add an extra routine to go through your links array and use the strings to extract the data object from your nodes hashmap.

```
var links_pointers = links.map(function(link){
       return {source:nodes[link.source], target:nodes[target.source]};
    });

var nodes_values = d3.values(nodes);

force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes_values)
    .links(links_pointers)
    /* etc. */
```

Then of course you can use the `links_pointers` array as the data for your `link` selection and change your tick function accordingly (to use `d.source.x` instead of `nodes[d.source].x`, etc.)